Is it possible to dynamically modify XHTML that is injected into React?
Context: I'm building a tool to browse the US Code, which the government provides in XML and XHTML formats. My plan at the moment is to store the full US Code in a MariaDB database, at a subsection granularity, then to have a Flask back end that queries from Maria and a React front end. Flask would return the subsection (or section) that the user searches for—e.g., Title 26, Section 162, Subsection (a)—and React would then sanitize (just in case) and inject the XHTML with dangerouslySetInnerHTML.
Here's my question... I want to enable users to make various readability enhancements on the fly, like graying out or collapsing parenthetical text, highlighting certain standard phrases such as "provided that," and the like. All of this would be done, at the most basic level, via options and checkboxes in the UI. Is there a way to modify the injected XHTML to reflect a given readability enhancement? E.g., the user searches for a section, the section gets injected, then the user activates the "provided that" highlighting—now, is there a way to apply that highlighting to the injected XHTML? Or, is injection—or React—not the right approach for this kind of use case?
